# Given a string, determine if a permutation of the string could form a palindrome in Java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, permutation, palindrome

I found a solution using a HashMap and I more or less understand what a HashMap is along with what map.getOrDefault() does but in this particular scenario, I am confused. Why is there a +1 and exactly what is it that we're adding to?

```
public boolean canPermutePalindrome(String s) {
    HashMap <Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        map.put(s.charAt(i), map.getOrDefault(s.charAt(i), 0) + 1); <-- I need a breakdown of this
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (char key: map.keySet()) {
        count += map.get(key) % 2;
    }
    
    return count <= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically all this computes how many times each character of the word is in the word itself.

That line of code put an entry to the map, initializing it with 1 or increment it by 1 if already there. The 'a+1' just counts the occurrencies of a character (1 if is put in the map for the first time, a+1 if the caracter is already in the map).

For a word to be palindrome each char should be an even number of times and maximum a character can be there once.